# Enable Input Mode To Hiragana when my application loads MFC C++

Tags: c++, mfc, ime

I want to make IME mode enabled and to set it to Hiragana in Japanese language by default when application laods and on set focus of EDIT field to disable it again to English,, I have tried many combinations but didn't resolved , i am  doing this -

On Set Focus of Edit Field-

```
HIMC himc = ImmGetContext(m_hWnd) ;
HIMC m_himc = ImmAssociateContext(this->m_hWnd, himc);
TCHAR key_layout[20];
DWORD langFlags=IME_CMODE_JAPANESE |IME_CMODE_NATIVE;

ImmSetOpenStatus(himc, TRUE);
ImmSetConversionStatus(himc, langFlags, NULL);
```

and on Kill Focus -

```
ImmSetOpenStatus(himc, FALSE);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I tried hit and trial and it worked , here is the solution
On Set Focus -

```
ImmAssociateContext(this->m_hWnd, NULL);
HIMC himc = ImmGetContext(this->m_hWnd);
ImmSetOpenStatus(himc, FALSE);
keyboard_layout= L"00000409";
LoadKeyboardLayout(keyboard_layout, KLF_ACTIVATE);
```

This will Off the IME on Entering Edit Field and and Set Language to English

On Kill Focus -

```
 HIMC himc = ImmGetContext(this->m_hWnd) ;
 ImmSetOpenStatus(himc, TRUE);
```

This will set the IME On when we leave the Edit Box